# How to concatenate string cell contents

Tags: python, python-2.7, xlsxwriter

I have this which works:

```
chart.set_title({'name': '=Sheet1!$A$2'})
```

What I want is functionally something like this;

```
chart.set_title({'name': '=Sheet1!$A$2' + ' to ' + '=Sheet1!$B$2'})
```

This gives an error of `Unknown worksheet reference`. Both cells contain dates, so it would look something like `1/1/2011 to 4/4/2014`. I can't find any examples [in the docs](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/) of how to do this.

Also tried this based on a now deleted proposed answer:

```
chart.set_title({'name': '=CONCATENATE(Sheet1!$A$2, " to ", Sheet1!$B$2)'})
```

It appears, however, that `set_title` does not accept formulas. It is possible to write this formula into a cell and then refer that cell in the `set_title`. A bit of a kluge:

```
worksheet.write(9, 20, '=CONCATENATE(Sheet1!$A$2, " to ", Sheet1!$B$2)')
chart.set_title({'name': '=Sheet1!$U$10'}) #(9,20)
```

Comment: what happens when you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm don't think that you want to do is possible in Excel.

Here is a working XlsxWriter example using the formula that you show above.

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('chart_column.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': 1})

headings = ['Number', 'Batch 1', 'Batch 2']
data = [
    [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    [10, 40, 50, 20, 10, 50],
    [30, 60, 70, 50, 40, 30],
]

worksheet.write_row('A1', headings, bold)
worksheet.write_column('A2', data[0])
worksheet.write_column('B2', data[1])
worksheet.write_column('C2', data[2])

chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'column'})

chart.add_series({
    'name':       '=Sheet1!$A$1',
    'categories': '=Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7',
    'values':     '=Sheet1!$B$2:$B$7',
})

chart.set_title({'name': '=CONCATENATE(Sheet1!$A$2, " to ", Sheet1!$B$2)'})

worksheet.insert_chart('E2', chart)

workbook.close()
```

This gives a warning but it still produces a valid workbook with a chart like this:

[image]

The title isn't visible but it you edit it the formula is there. However, if you try to change it Excel complains that it isn't a valid formula. So, it looks like Excel doesn't support this feature.

If you think that it is possible in Excel and can show an example I'll look into how it can be supported in XlsxWriter.

Comment: A response from the author of the API, I'm honored. The question doesn't involve the series title, but rather the chart title. As a separate matter I had tried using individual series as you do here, but, as you say, the name of the individual series is not visible and so I cannot use it. As I say in an edit to my original question, I can get what I want by writing the formula to a cell and then referring the title to the cell. I find I am having to do this sort of trick in several places as a work around to get what I need. I need to play with this more to see if there are better solutions.

Comment: I've updated the example so that it relates to the chart title rather than the series name. However, the same point applies: it isn't possible to use a formula like this in Excel.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I didn't mean to imply that this was a limitation of Xlsxwriter. It is indeed a limitation of Excel.